# Look for a string in a data frame and select the rows with R

Tags: r, string, select, date-range

I have a table like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 1 | k1 |
| B | k | 2 | k2 |
| C | z | 3 | k3 |
| D | y | 4 | k4 |

I would like to write a script which selects a specific string and gives me back that row. For example, I want to see the rows which contains "A", which can be in every column. I tried str_detect, but you have to specify the column in the data frame which I don't want to. Also it would be perfect to have it selecting different strings, like look for "A", "3" and "y" with this output:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 1 | k1 |
| C | z | 3 | k3 |
| D | y | 4 | k4 |

Comment: Can you provide some example code. Also I would use dplyr with across. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

Comment: I tried str detect and grep to look for a string and getting back the rows, the thing is that you have to specify the column and I don't need that

Comment: I corrected it Akrun, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `if_any` with `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(if_any(everything(), ~ str_detect(.x, 'A|3|y')))
```

-output

```
  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1       A       x       1      k1
2       C       z       3      k3
3       D       y       4      k4
```

---

Or using `base R` with a non-regex solution

```
subset(df1, Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, \(x) x %in% c('A', 3, 'y'))))
  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1       A       x       1      k1
3       C       z       3      k3
4       D       y       4      k4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), ColumnB = c("x", 
"k", "z", "y"), ColumnC = 1:4, ColumnD = c("k1", "k2", "k3", 
"k4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vec <- c('A', 3, 'y') 
df[rowsum(+(as.matrix(df) %in% vec), c(row(df)))>0,]

  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1       A       x       1      k1
3       C       z       3      k3
4       D       y       4      k4
```

Another way is useing regex:

```
df[grepl(sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste0(vec, collapse = '|')), do.call(paste, df)), ]
  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1       A       x       1      k1
3       C       z       3      k3
4       D       y       4      k4
```